# Mobile automation script fails when the email verification site is not working

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, email-validation, email-verification

Steps are:

1. I click on my app.
2. Enter the email address and click on submit button. Then I receive a message as check your inbox.
3. In the email, I receive a email verification link.
4. Once I click on that email verification link, my app proceeds to next screen.

The problem is my script is getting failed as I am using https://temp-mail.io/en for email verification. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work. The problem is out of 10 times 2 times the site "https://temp-mail.io/en" get's blocked.

Could you please help me is there any other way to do this task.

I tried other sites for email verification, still getting the same issue.

Comment: when you say its blocked, is your app is not sending the email to the temp address?

Comment: @AbhayChaudhary My mobile app is sending link to the https://temp-mail.io/en but the "https://temp-mail.io/en" site itself is not loading due to which my script is getting failed.

Comment: @AbhayChaudhary Also I refered "https://angiejones.tech/test-automation-to-verify-email/" but unable to process with this solution.

Could you please help me how to use "javax.mail-api" dependecy to read the mail body?

Right now we are facing issue to connect with email server by using "https://angiejones.tech/test-automation-to-verify-email/"